# GitPython - cannot get index for repo?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

How on earth does one get the index for a repos using GitPython ?

```
import git

repo = git.Repo.init('/path/to/repos/')
... add some files ...
... commit ...
index = repo.index()
```

Throw error: 'Repo' object has no attribute 'index'

WTH? My eyes are bloody from reading the Trier tutorial over and over getting nowhere fast.
Clues anyone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here.  First, `index` isn't method, it's an `IndexFile` object. Secondly, I wonder if you're not using the current version of GitPython.

If I start with:

```
$ virtualenv stacktest
$ ./stacktext/bin/pip install GitPython
$ ./stackext/bin/python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 12 2013, 16:18:42) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20131017 (Red Hat 4.8.2-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import git
>>> repo = git.Repo.init('/home/username/projects/myproject')
>>> repo.index
<git.index.base.IndexFile object at 0x1213a48>
>>> repo.index.entries
{('README.md', 0): (100644, 515cbd1e78aa13ec91941eaa63ecec89d5e4b947, 0, README.md), ('setup.py', 0): (100644, 7497e295447af70a6865b7313bfb2f86ba6577d6, 0, setup.py)}
```

Another possibility is that something in your code is masking the attribute.  If you can post an actual *runnable* code sampe that someone else can run, that will help narrow down the problem.

Comment: I thinkn you may have hit it in one: `pip freeze` shows me GitPython == 0.1.7.  For some reason that is all that pip install will give me. Running easy_installl GitPython gets me up to date.